Draw line and calculate distance from each no adjoining side polygons to perpendicular nearest side polygon
From a polygon geometry layer representing building boundaries, I show a screenshot:

I would like to calculate, for each building polygon, the distance from each side of the polygon that has no adjoining polygons, to the side of the perpendicular nearest polygon.
The idea is to use an expression for Geometry Generator to draw a line, and another expression for labeling to label the street width distance for each building.
As an example I add a screenshot with the simulated result done by hand:


Do you have a small sample dataset you can add?

Yes, a full copy of the parcel polygon layer in GML format can be downloaded from the following link:
[link]http://www.catastro.minhap.es/INSPIRE/CadastralParcels/24/24900-LEON/A.ES.SDGC.CP.24900.zip
The name of the layer is: A.ES.SDGC.CP.24900.cadastralparcel.gml
To have a simplified dataset, you can use this filter ("localId" LIKE '%TN%'), or make a manual selection of a few urban buildings

This is an expression for drawing the lines using the Geometry by Expression tool (QGIS 3.36.2). It works also as a Geometry Generator symbol layer, but this causes difficulties when calculating and displaying the line lengths (explained at the end).
It is a little complex so feel free to ask for clarification on any elements that are unclear.
I applied the expression only to the middle block for demonstration purposes. Otherwise, the output is very busy.
Don't forget to change 'parcels' to your layer name / ID.

-- apply expression only to middle block for demonstration using an attribute field called subset
case when subset = true then

collect_geometries(
    -- remove null values from resulting array
    array_filter(

        -- loop though each segment of the current polygon feature
        array_foreach(
            geometries_to_array(
                -- simplify is used else there are many segments
                segments_to_lines(simplify(@geometry, 1))
            ),
            
            -- find the midpoint of the segment
            with_variable('mid',
                line_interpolate_point(@element, length(@element) / 2),
                
                -- project a line from the midpoint of the segment outwards
                -- to find the  outwards direction for the line, I scaled the polygon up slightly and found the nearest point on this slightly larger version from the segment midpoint
                with_variable('azi', 
                    azimuth(
                        @mid,
                        closest_point(boundary(scale(@geometry, 1.01, 1.01)), @mid)
                    ),
                    
                    -- project the line (or ray) using the azimuth found above. In this case by 50 m but this can be changed if necessary
                    with_variable('ray', 
                        make_line(
                            @mid,
                            project(@mid, 50, @azi)
                        ),
                        
                        -- filter out rays that intersect with the original layer so that only those on the edge of a block are drawn
                        case when 
                            not intersects(line_substring(@ray, 1, 2), aggregate('parcels', 'collect', @geometry)) 
                        then 
                    
                        -- remove intersections of rays with the original layer
                        with_variable('diff', 
                            difference(@ray, aggregate('parcels', 'collect', @geometry)),
                            
                            -- sometimes a ray would overshoot the adjacent block and have a segment the other side of it, so here only the first segment is captured
                            case when 
                                num_geometries(@diff) > 1 
                            then 
                                geometry_n(@diff, 1) 
                            else 
                                @diff
                            end
                        )
                        end
                    )
                    
                )
                
            )
        ),
        @element is not NULL
    )
)

end

Although the lines can be drawn using a Geometry Generator symbol layer, the lengths of the lines cannot be reliably labelled. This is because a layer is labeled per feature. In this case there are 9 features (blue polygons) but 20 resulting lines. The output is a MultiLine with some polygons having several lines, resulting in an array of lengths. There is  no way to know which length in the array belongs to which line and due to it being a MultiLine they cannot be placed at their proper location.
To properly get and display the lengths, the expression must be used in the Geometry by Expression tool followed by Multipart to singleparts. The expression for the length is then just length(@geometry).

It works exactly as my project needs it to. I just have one question: I understand that you create the boolean field 'subset' to filter a single block in this example. Can you confirm this? Everything else, awesome job!

Indeed, yes. Otherwise, there were lines everywhere and it didn't make for a good screenshot :)

Useful question and impressive answer
